# Making div scrollable which have many div as column wise inside it

Tags: html, css

I want to make following screen

[image: Design pic]

HTML code

```
  <div class="outerDiv">

     <div class="column">

            <div class="row columnName">Column Name 1</div>

            <div class="row value">Value 1</div>

            <div class="row value">Value 2</div>

            <div class="row value">Value 3</div>

            <div class="row value">Value 4</div>

    </div>

    <div class="column">
            <div class="row columnName">Column Name 2</div>

            <div class="row value">Value 1</div>

            <div class="row value">Value 2</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Outer div contains many div as columns and width of column will be fixed but height of column will be vary according to containt of that column div.

I want outer div scrollable. It should scroll horizontal to see all other columns and scroll vertically to see if any column's height go out of outer div

I have implemented following css

```
.outerDiv{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}
.column{
 width:20%;
 height:100%;
 float:left;
 display:inline;
 margin-right:10px;
 }
.row{
 width:100%;
 height:10%;
}
.value{
 font-size:18px;
}
```

so the problem, Columns div are coming down, outer div is not horizontally scrolling, verticall sroll is working fine. Please help me I have tried whole day :(

JS fidler: http://jsfiddle.net/Raj_13290/LG8j9/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell` in your `.column` CSS class to display columns side by side and  `white-space: nowrap;` in `.outerDiv` to show column names in one line (otherwise they will be gripped at the end).

```
.outerDiv{
   overflow:auto;
   white-space: nowrap;

}
.column{
   width:20%;
   height:100%;
   display:table-cell;
   padding:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LG8j9/13/)

Comment: Thank you It worked. But it seems width and margin is not working for column class

Comment: I have marked as answered. But width is not working even for px

Answer (score 0):

Change width value in outerDiv class to fixed value witdh:1000% or width: 3000px;
The witdh value has to bigger than the width of the screen.